# Dynamically assign values to spinner

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, spinner

Is This piece of code correct

```
static_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            option=static_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (option){
                case "option1":
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Upload.this,R.array.list11,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    break;
                case "option2":
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Upload.this,R.array.list22,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    break;
                case "option2":
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Upload.this,R.array.list33,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    break;
                case "option3":
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Upload.this,R.array.list44,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    break;
            }
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner_dynamic.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

list11, list22, list33 and list44 is specified in string as an array.

i want to assign one of those arrays as entries to the spinner_dynamic based of the selection in the static_spinner.

Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: Is the code not working or do you get error logs? The code looks like it should be working

Comment: every time i launch the activity, it says my app stopped working and goes back to the previous activity. and btw these codes are placed in th activity on create function

Comment: i found that the error is in the array adapter. i removed those codes and its working fine. Isn't there any method to assign value to spinner dynamically???

Comment: Can edit the error log into your question above?

Comment: i got it. thanks anyway mate